# building blog using react.js and express.js

Tags: reactjs

I am a web developer tries to learn React.js. I am thinking about a blog for my first React project. Based on articles and tutorials I have read in the past few days, I am thinking about to use Node.js, Express.js and MongoDB for my server side and React.js for the front-end. Before I start, I want to be clear on few questions I have.

1. Are those enough to build a blog? Can React.js be used for UI without other template library such as Handlebars?? I have seen few articles using both React and Template engine and confused if I am going to need another template engine.
2. Can I use Json as communication method(Restful API) between the UI and the server?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for all. But I suggest to use Redus(or Flax) to control all states.